# DynamicUpdate annotation in Spring Data JPA and Audit fields

Tags: spring-data-jpa

I have a HTML form. When I submit the form, data either gets inserted or updated by Spring data JPA.
I added the @DynamicUpdate annotation to my entity class since I wanted the update statement to only include the columns that were actually changed on the form. This worked fine but I ran into one issue.

I have an audit column called last_updated_user_id in my database table. It tracks the user who inserted or last updated the record. My Spring entity class has a field that is mapped to the above column.

So if I first login as user X(say, userid=10) and submit the HTML form, the last_updated_user_id will be set to 10 and a new record will be inserted into my table. If another user now logs in as user Y(say, userid=20) and submits the HTML form with the same data(i.e. they pulled up the same record, didn't change anything and clicked submit), the record gets updated in my table. All the values are the same except that the last_updated_user_id is now set to 20.
So there was no change to the data, but since the last_updated_user_id changed, spring data JPA thinks there is a change to the entity and it updates the record in my table.

I can compare the old & new values of all the **data fields** in my entity class and call the .save() method only if something has changed.

The other option is for me to compare the old & new values on the client side and only trigger a call to the server if something has changed. Let's say the  data on the form is stored in 3 different tables in the database. If the user changes the data related to only 1 table on the form, it will trigger a call to the server and spring data JPA will again update all 3 tables since all 3 entity classes have the last_updated_user_id field.
So I will still have to compare the old and new values of all the **data fields** in each entity class and call the .save() method only if something has changed.

There are more than 30 fields on my form and I'm trying to avoid writing code to compare all 30. If there's a better way to handle this with Spring data JPA, please let me know.